# Textmate and add existing files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, filesystems, textmate

I don't understand why when I add files to my project using add existing files from project try it does not copy the file to my project, it just copies the reference to the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In TextMate, **a project is** nothing more than **a collection of references to files** you can edit simultaneously. It enables you to have them open in a drawer and as tabs as you will most certainly know already. But a TextMate project is not intended to be a file manager. More information on handling files inside a project can be found at the [TextMate manual](http://manual.macromates.com/en/working_with_multiple_files).

Comment: i have no what to say, looks like i will need to copy files manually in finder: http://goo.gl/EjnSN

Answer (score 0):

Add the folder to your project drawer on the left then you will be able to drag the files from there into your Rails project.

I was running to the same problem with trying to add existing files to a folder in my project, it would not change the reference.